# Showing a solution is $T$-periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $T > 0$ and suppose $a$ and $b$ are continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a(t + T) \equiv a(t)$ and $b(t + T) \equiv b(t)$. Show that if $y$ is a solution to
>   \begin{align} y' = a(t)y + b(t)\end{align}
>   and $\bar{y}(t) \equiv y(t+T)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\bar{y}$ is also a solution to this equation.

Let $y$ be a solution to the given equation and set $\bar{y}(t) \equiv y(t+T)$. Then,

$$ \bar{y}' = a(t)\bar{y} + b(t) \implies y(t+T) = a(t+T)y(t+T) + b(t+T) $$

but since $a$ and $b$ are periodic, then
$$ y(t+T) = a(t)y(t+T) + b(t). $$

What must I connect from here?

Comment: Why are you starting from $\overline{y}' = a(t)\overline{y}+b(t)$? This is what you want to show, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Is the question still standing (how to prove that $\overline{y}$ is a solution)?

Comment: Yes, how to show that $\bar{y}$ as defined is a solution.

Comment: $\bar{y}' = y'$ isn't it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Use that $y$ is a solution to compute $d/dt [y(t+T)]$...

Comment: Does the result follow since  $\frac{d}{dt}\big[y(t+T)] = y'(t+T) = \bar{y}'$?

Comment: Do you mean $\overline{y}'$? Then, yes, it basically follows from that (now just plug in the differential equation for $y'(t+T)$).